# AWS RDS - MsSql - Create schema, user or role in "master" or "msdb" databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS MsSql express V13.
I'm trying to create a schema, user and role using the root user I created during the RDS setup but can't. I'm using SQL client.

for example:

```
use [master]
CREATE USER [my_user] FOR LOGIN [my_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

returns: "User does not have permission to perform this action."

Answer (score 3):

AWS RDS restricts permissions on the `master` database, so you can't create schemas, roles, users, or logins there.

You need to create a second database, which will then allow you to create schemas, users, and roles as expected.

```
-- use the master database to create your new database:
USE master;  
CREATE DATABASE db_test;

-- then, use your new database to create your schema, login, and user:
USE db_test;
CREATE SCHEMA yourschema;
CREATE LOGIN [youruser] WITH PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>';
CREATE USER [youruser] FOR LOGIN [youruser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [yourschema];
```