# Create permission denied ON AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created a RDS instance for Microsoft SQL Server, while creating the instance I have master user named admin.

Now the issue is I have created a new user with these privileges added to it:

```
PROCESSADMIN 
SETUPADMIN 
DB_OWNER
```

According the documents given in the below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html, we should have access to create databases with the above privileges, but I am not able to create a new database with this user.

Can anyone guide me if I am missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with Amazon support? They would be the ones to know ...

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315519/aws-rds-mssql-create-schema-user-or-role-in-master-or-msdb-databases/50805928#50805928

Comment: @AdilB Nope My issue here is am not able to create the database itself, if I have to create a database then i need to use the RDS SQL server master user. But what I am trying to achieve here is that I have created another with the permission mentioned above, but for that user is failing to create a new database itself do you have any idea on that or does it mean only the RDS master user will have permission to create a new database and all other remaining users which we create will not. Thank you!

Comment: @marc_s No I haven't reached amazon support on this.